# Parse server query object is returning no results

Tags: parse-platform

I am having issues with querying the parse server. I have created a class called Tickets and a single row via the Dashboard. When I use curl, I can query and get the row. However, when I try to do it in JavaScript from an HTML page, I get zero results.

I call the getTickets() function from myLogin, which is called via a button click. The final console.log() call in getTickets() prints "Results: " and nothing else.

BTW, the getTickets() function is modeled on [examples](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#queries) in the Parse documentation.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is my code:

```
    Parse.initialize("-REDACTED-", "");
    Parse.serverURL = "-REDACTED-";

    function myLogin(uname, psw) {
      var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
      var psw = document.getElementById("psw").value;
      const user = Parse.User.logIn(uname, psw);
      var cUser = Parse.User.current();

      if (cUser) {
        console.log(
          "Hey! The login worked!" + " Username: " + cUser.get("username")
        );
        getTickets();
      } else {
        alert("Womp, womp. The login failed.");
      }
    }

    async function getTickets() {
      const Ticket = Parse.Object.extend("Ticket");
      const query = new Parse.Query(Ticket);
      const res = await query.find();
      console.log("Results: " + res);
    }
```

The curl call returns the following, if that's useful:

```
{"results":[{"objectId":"RuFPxSjigL","user":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"uGwwN99EX9"},"createdAt":"2020-01-15T20:47:45.116Z","updatedAt":"2020-01-15T20:48:05.203Z","event":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Event","objectId":"BdGQSPhK0J"}}]}%
```

Comment: Show me your `curl` call, please. Also, is the request successful in the browser's "Network" tab?

Comment: Here is the curl call:

`curl -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: -REDACTED-" \
     https://www.myexample.com/parse/classes/Ticket`

Yes. The request got a status of 200 and the network tab indicates that 262 bytes were returned.

Thanks.

Comment: BTW, the login above the getTickets() call works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are minor things I'd change:

```
Parse.initialize("imAppId", "");
Parse.serverURL = "https://www.immedia.co/parse/";

async function imLogin(uname, psw) {
  const uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
  const psw = document.getElementById("psw").value;
  let user;
  try {
    user = await Parse.User.logIn(uname, psw);
  } catch (err) {
    alert("Login failed: username or password are not valid: ", err);
    return; // if log in fails, you can't access the user's tickets
  }

  let tix;
  try {
    tix = await getTickets();
    alert("Successfully retrieved " + tix.length + " tickets.");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error getting tickets: ", err);
    return;
  }

  for (const obj of tix) {
    console.log(
      "ticket.id: " + obj.id + " with user.id " + obj.get("user")
    );
  }
}

async function getTickets() {
  const Ticket = Parse.Object.extend("Ticket");
  const query = new Parse.Query(Ticket);
  return await query.find();
}
```

You can convert the `for` loop to a [for-of loop](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_core-features.html#sec_for-foreach-forof). I'd not catch an error in `getTickets`, but in the log in function. And if log in or get tickets fails, `return` after logging the error, as there's nothing more to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I didn't understand that the Parse.Query.find() returns an array. The console.log() call in getTickets(), indicated that res was undefined and I thought that nothing was being returned. I have updated my code to behave better. I am new to JavaScript, I would appreciate any suggestions to improve the code or the style.

```
    Parse.initialize("imAppId", "");
    Parse.serverURL = "https://www.immedia.co/parse/";

    async function imLogin(uname, psw) {
      var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
      var psw = document.getElementById("psw").value;
      var user;
      try {
        user = await Parse.User.logIn(uname, psw);
      } catch (err) {
        alert("Login failed: username or password are not valid: ", err);
      }

      const tix = await getTickets();

      for (let i = 0; i < tix.length; i++) {
        var obj = tix[i];
        console.log(
          "ticket.id: " + obj.id + " with user.id " + obj.get("user")
        );
      }

      async function getTickets() {
      const Ticket = Parse.Object.extend("Ticket");
      const query = new Parse.Query(Ticket);
      var tix = [];
      try {
        tix = await query.find();
        alert("Successfully retrieved " + tix.length + " tickets.");
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error getting tickets: ", err);
      }
      return tix;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what fixed your problem. Before and after you did `await new Parse.Query(Ticket).find()` and output the return value to the console. Did you overlook the result in the console in your first post?

Comment: Yeah. Exactly. I missed that result was an array containing the query results. When I printed it, the log message said "undefined" and that threw me off.